# use "of" alongside "aim"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, spoken-english

I am not sure which sentence is correct:

> with the aim of raising awareness

Or

> With the aim to raise awareness

Comment: *As far as I remember, it is incorrect to use "of" alongside "aim."* I have no idea why you think this. In your context "the aim" is a noun phrase. In "with the aim of X", "of X" is a prepositional modifier that modifies "the aim". All nouns/noun phrases may be qualified by a prepositional modifier.

Comment: I assume the OP is confusing "aim" as a verb which takes prepositions such as "at" and "for", with "aim" as a noun, which can indeed by used with "of".

Comment: Choose between *with the aim of doing X* and *aiming to do X*. Avoid *with the aim to do X* (which I wouldn't say is "ungrammatical" - just "not very idiomatic").

Comment: “With ***an*** aim to raise awareness”  seems much better to me.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question Krishnapriya. The forms "aim to" or "aim at" are correct when "aim" is used as a verb.  However, "aim" is also a noun, as in your example of "with the aim of raising awareness".

When [***aim*** is a noun](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aim), "aim of" is perfectly correct, followed by the -ing form of verb (participle).

I might say "I aim to hit my fitness target by training every day." or I could say "I train every day with the aim of hitting my fitness target".